# ionic 4 make ion-item transparent depending upon selected value

Tags: css, ionic4

If selected value using `<select>` is greater than the value in the database, I want to make that particular `ion-item` transparent or blur. For that, I have a property called disabled. But I can't dynamically make ion-item transparent.
Thank you in advance

```
  onChange(new_quantity,object, stock  ) {
    let stocks = stock

     for(let i=0; i<stocks.length; i++) {
            if(new_quantity > stocks[i].RemainingQuantity){


              console.log(new_quantity)
              console.log(object.quantity)
              console.log(stocks[i].RemainingQuantity)

              object.disabled = true
              console.log("quantity not available")

              this.presentAlert()
            }
    }
}
```

html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let p of cart ;  let i=index" class="ion-text-wrap">

            <ion-grid>

              <div class="ion-text-end" *ngIf="p.disabled">
                <ion-label color="tertiary">Out of stock</ion-label>
              </div>

     <select style="max-width:50%;" (change)="onChange($event.target.value, p, p.product.stocks) " [value]=p.quantity  > 

      <option  [ngValue] = "q" *ngFor ="let q of quantity" >{{q}}</option>
      </select>
      </ion-grid>

        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by just passing the index of the cart to check the products stock. If you get the value of the `ion-select` with ngModel, you can access that value directly in the function without passing it in.

There we loop your selected products stock. If the remainingQuantity is less than your productQuantity, the cart is disabled. This will add a new css class `item-disabled` to your item, which sets the background to transparent.

#### Html

```html
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let c of cart; let i=index" class="ion-text-wrap" [ngClass]="{ 'item-transparent': c.disabled  }">
    <ion-grid>
      <div class="ion-text-end" *ngIf="c.disabled">
        <ion-label color="tertiary">Out of stock</ion-label>
      </div>
      <ion-select style="max-width:50%;" [(ngModel)]="productQuantity" (ionChange)="checkIfProductIsOutOfStock(i)" value="c.quantity"> 
        <ion-select-option value="quantity" *ngFor="let quantity of c.quantity">{{ quantity }}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

#### Ts

```js
productQuantity: number;

checkIfProductIsOutOfStock(index: number) {
  const stocks = this.cart[index].products.stocks;

  stocks.forEach((stock: object) => {
    if (this.productQuantity > stock['RemainingQuantity'] {
      this.cart[index].disabled = true;
    }
  });
}
```

#### Css

```css
.item-transparent {
  --background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is a small problem. How to set default value of ion-select. value= "p.quantity" not working

Comment: Good question. Maybe change the value to the first instance of your `p.quantity`. So the value becomes `value= "p.quantity[0]"`. Can you try?